# Reflection Probability for Different Potentials - Quantum Mechanics

Tags: probability, quantum-mechanics, reflection

[image: Question]

My question is above. Firstly, I don't actually know whether it is true or not (!). Secondly, if I were to try to prove it, then I have very little idea how to. The potential steps that I have always done are steps from a constant level to another constant level (Heavyside), whereas this is different.

I would imagine the answer is yes, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Can I approximate the curve by small steps (/sums of Heavyside functions), and then show that a larger Heavyside step gives a larger probability?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Seeing that this is not [physics.se], you should target the question at mathematical audience. What is the mathematical relation between $p_i$ and $V_i$?

Comment: I realise that this isn't physics, hence being in the maths part! =P The issue is that I can't determine the relation. :(

Comment: I mean this site is not Physics.SE: it's Mathematics.SE. And you don't have a clear *mathematical* question here.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. But no, this is a _maths_ QM question, not a physics QM question. "Justify your answer carefully, either by giving a rigorous proof or by presenting a counterexample with explicit calculations of $p_1$ and $p_2$." That's maths, no physics. =P

Comment: Also, it's a past paper from the maths university course that I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily true. For a zero potential $V_2$ you have $p_2=0$, whereas if $V_1$ is a rectangular pit, in general, $p_1>0$.

Comment: So the natural question is: is the reverse inequality true?

Comment: Ah yes, I thought that it was $V_i \ge 0$! It's clearly not true as said. How about the reverse inequality then, or when $V_1(x) \ge V_2(x) \ge 0$?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac: I don't think the reverse inequality is necessarily true. I don't have a proof, but I would think that a smoother but a bit deeper pit would reflect less than an "inscribed" rectangular pit.

Comment: Ok yeah, thank you. Also, sorry that this is on physics.SE. It's definitely a _maths_ question, not a physics question, but someone decided to migrate it ¬_¬. I don't have the possibility to migrate it back, otherwise I would. Still, at least it meant that you saw the question! :)

Comment: @Smiley Sam: I am not sure what you have in mind, but the considerations in my previous comment can be somewhat relevant.

Comment: @SmileySam: This is very much a physics question.

Comment: Erm, it's in the _maths_ tripos. :P QM obviously has a lot of overlap, but the question is looking at the maths behind QM, not the physics.

Comment: @Smiley Sam: I don't know, I would say this is definitely a question for Physics.SE:-)

Comment: It isn't out of place here for certain, but it definitely is not out of place on Maths.SE, since it is explicitly a maths question. Hence why I'm a bit annoyed that someone thought he was better than me and had the right to move my question about when I disagreed. Still, what can you do with some people eh? :) At least I've been able to get a very clear and helpful answer from you, so thank you for that! =D

Comment: @Smiley Sam: You are welcome. And, by the way, it looks like the person whose action (moving your question to Physics.SE) irritated you, actually helped you:-)

Comment: Good can come from bad things! =D